# COMODO SSL certificate on Jboss7

Tags: java, ssl, jboss7.x

I registered a domain and would like to set up SSL encryption for it. My domain provider offered me to get a SSL certificate from COMODO. I generated a key and a csr file using openSSL:

```
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout myserver.key -out server.csr
```

The command produced a private key, myserver.key and the csr file. I uploaded the content of the csr to comodo, and after verification, they sent me the following files:

```
Root CA Certificate - AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
Intermediate CA Certificate - COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
Intermediate CA Certificate - COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
Your PositiveSSL Certificate - mydomain.crt
```

I'm lost on where to go from here. I followed these instructions:

https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/638/0/certificate-installation-java-based-web-servers-tomcat-using-keytool

and created a domain.keystore file, but I'm not sure if that's the right thing to do or not. My configuration in Jboss now looks like this:

```
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
    <ssl name="mydomain" password="*****" protocol="TLSv1" certificate-key-file="../standalone/configuration/domain.keystore"/>
</connector>
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I get no error in the server log, the page simply times out. If i use http it works normally. Any advice?

EDIT:

I took a different approach, I generated my keystore in this way:

```
keytool -genkey -alias domain -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore domain.keystore
```

then I uploaded the new csr info to comodo and got the three .crt certificates back. I imported them into the keystore with this command:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias domain -file domain.crt -keystore domain.keystore
```

and then I used the keystore in the standalone.xml in this way:

```
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
    <ssl name="domain-ssl" key-alias="domain" password="******" certificate-key-file="../standalone/configuration/domain.keystore" protocol="TLSv1"/>
</connector>
```

The server starts, but when I try to connect to it, my browser says that the connection is untrusted:

```
domain uses an invalid security certificate.
The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed.
(Error code: sec_error_ca_cert_invalid)
```

Comment: "private key, myserver.key, ..." - they should be the same thing. What's the difference between them?

Comment: My bad, I wrote it in a weird way, it's the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed to get the installation right! Here's how you do it:

Install the COMODO certificates into your keystore wit this command:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias <filename> -file <filename>.crt -keystore domain.keystore
```

in the following order:

```
» Root: AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
» Intermediate 1: COMODOAddTrustServerCA.crt
» Intermediate 2: COMODOExtendedValidationSecureServerCA.crt
```

Then install your domain certificate:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias mykey -file yourDomainName.crt -keystore domain.keystore
```

You should use the same alias instead of mykey, that you used to generate your keystore. If you do everything correctly, you should get this output:

```
Certificate reply was installed in keystore
```

Anything else means, you probably didn't use the correct alias. The final thing you need to do is to modify your standalone.xml like this:

```
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
    <ssl name="<domain>-ssl" key-alias="<domain>" password="******" certificate-key-file="../standalone/configuration/<domain>.keystore"/>
</connector>
```

And you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> My domain provider offered me to get a SSL certificate from COMODO...
> ...
> Any advice?
> ```

Don't pay for the certificate. You can get a free Class 1 certificate from [Startcom](https://www.startcom.org/). The Class 1 is good for server authentication *without* a wildcard domain. If you want an extended validation certificate or a wilcard certificate, then you will have to buy a Class 2 or higher.

Also, while [Startcom](https://www.startcom.org/) issues the certificate for free, they charge for revocation because that's where the cost lies.

---

> I'm lost on where to go from here...

Convert `Intermediate CA Certificate - COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt`, `Intermediate CA Certificate - COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt` and `Your PositiveSSL Certificate - mydomain.crt` to PEM files. PEM are the ones that start with `----- BEGIN CERTIFICATE -----` and finish with `----- END CERTIFICATE -----`.

Then, concatenate your three PEM files into a single file. The file will have three certificates in it. Call it `mydomain-chain.pem`, and load that into your server. Also load `myserver.key` into your server.

Don't do anything with `Root CA Certificate - AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt`. Clients have to use it as a root. There's no {use|need} to send it to the client in the `ServerHello`.

You can test your setup with the following. Notice how the client uses the root:

```
openssl s_client -connect myserver:443 -CAfile AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
```

The command should end with `Verify (0) OK` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried what you described, but now on server startup I get the following error:

ERROR [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory] (MSC service thread 1-1) Failed to load keystore type JKS with path ../standalone/configuration/mydomain-chain.pem due to Invalid keystore format: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

Answer (score 0):

Failed to load keystore type JKS with path ../standalone/configuration/mydomain-chain.pem due to Invalid keystore format: which mean your keystore is not valid. Dont create new one use the keystore file you were created while submitting csr file to them. Use same keystore if you change the keystore its not accept.